# Money-rails showing amounts as thousands

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with rails-money

My invoices model:

```
monetize :payment_cents
```

This column exists, on my /clients/index

```
 <td><%= number_to_currency(invoice.payment_cents) %></td>
```

I get tens of thousands instead of hundres

[image]

Am I missing something, a migration perhaps, renaming my payments_cents to :cents? or perhaps in my model to define how to show the currency. On the /clients/show and form pages it appears as such
[image]

which is fine! Can anyone help?

Comment: what does `invoice.payment_cents` returns?

Comment: It returns the same amount without the decimals or commas and without the dollar sign

Comment: so it returns 20000 and you wanted 200. Is that right?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `number_to_currency`.

You can instead use their own helper

```
humanized_money_with_symbol(invoice.payment_cents)
```

If it doesn't work, try the following.

```
invoice_payment = '%.2f' % (invoice.payment_cents.to_i/100.0) # -> 200.00

humanized_money_with_symbol(invoice_payment) # -> $200.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much Roshan I’ll give it a try today

Comment: I tried the humanized_money_with_symbol helper however for some reason the rails-money gem has added zeros to my numbers

Comment: @EvanRoberts If rails-money gem doesn't work well for you, try [Money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). rails-money gem is a fork of this gem.